# I installed Pillow and am trying to use from PIL import Image but it gives an error

Tags: python, import, pip, python-imaging-library

I have installed Pillow (7.2.0) but when I use

`from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont`

it gives me this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`

What can I do? I did `pip install Pillow`. I've tried uninstalling and installing pillow but it did not work. I am on windows and have python 3.7

Comment: pip install Pillow==2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to get the latest version of Pillow

```
pip install wheel
pip install Pillow
```

I have done it in Google Colab
[image]

Comment: when I tried this the command errored out when "running setup.py install for Pillow"

Comment: check the pip version using  `pip --version`

Comment: I think you have python 2.7 and python 3.7

Comment: pip3 install Pillow==2.2.1

Comment: i have pip version 20.2.3

Comment: Use pip3 to install Pillow

Comment: I'm working on visual studio but am typing these into command prompt

Comment: `easy-install-3.6 install pip`
`pip3 install pillow`
It might work

Comment: when i try "easy-install-3.6 install pip" i get:
'easy-install-3.6' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: pip install wheel
pip install Pillow

Comment: I still get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' when I run my program